# How can I permanently increase a number (variable) in python?

Tags: python, excel, variables

I'm writing a program that registers expenses in an excel file using openpyxl, but I need to specify the cell number, for example, the first expense should be registered in cell A1 and the second expense in A2 and so forth.

I need to set a variable that can increase when an expense is registered, and I need it to stay that way when I close the program.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to persist a value between executions of a program is to store this value somewhere where you can read it back at startup - a plain text file is usually a good solution for a single or small set of values but if you already have an excel sheet you could as well store your value in the spreadsheet itself. But it's even safer to not rely on stored values for things you can easily compute - in your case by finding the first empty cell.

Answer (score 1):

parse the excel file get the sheet.ncols and you have your registered variable.